# Why my method to get euler numbers, return infinity?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, eulers-number

Im trying to get the euler number, with Javascript.

Here my code, that return infinity:

```js
function euler_number() {
  for(var j = 0, e = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      e += 1/(factorial(j));
  }
  return e;
}

function factorial(n) {
  if(n <= 1) return n;
  return factorial(n - 1) * n;
}

var r = euler_number();

console.log(r);
```

so, i cant understand why it return infinity.

Comment: `(factorial(j)` when `j=0` is `0` and `1/0` ? what else do you expect ?

Comment: To add to the other comment, you may want to change the return to 1, since `0! === 1`. eg `if (n <= 1) return 1`

Comment: Also it's unclear from the title if you're trying to generate the famous [Euler constant `e`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), or if you're trying to generate one of the [Euler Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number), although the code clearly indicates the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code returns infinity because the initial value of `j` is `0`.  In particular, you're adding `1/factorial(0)` to `e`.  What does `factorial(0)` return? JavaScript evaluates `1/0` as `Infinity`, so after the first iteration, `e` is already `Infinity`, and any subsequent iterations add more to it.

To fix this, just start `j` at 1.  That should do the trick!

Edit: Vasan had a great point, which is that 0! (0 factorial) [actually evaluates to 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Definition).  For a better fix, you should reevaluate your `factorial` function.

Comment: _What does factorial(0) return?_ - that is the real problem, a faulty factorial implementation..

Comment: @Mattiu I've rolled back your edit, since it removed the problem that this answer addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Because your first value of j is 0. You divide that by zero and get infinity in JS. Whatever you add to it is still infinity

The following is your value of j in each of the 10 iteration

Infinity,
1,
0.5,
0.3333333333333333,
0.25,
0.2,
0.16666666666666666,
0.14285714285714285,
0.125,
0.1111111111111111,